# optimizing a slow aggregation mongo query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections forms4InsTrader_final (2 mil documents) and TradeData (13 mil documents). **I am having really difficult time to understand why `$out` is not saving results of aggregation.**

In the following aggregation there are following stages:

1. Stage 1: `$match` dates between  certain date range.
   `{'pdOfRpt': {'$gte': '2004-01-01', '$lte': '2020-12-31' }}`
2. Stage 2: Join (`$lookup`) the `forms4InsTrader_final` to `TradeData`
   `{'from': 'aprl_test_Trade', 'localField': 'issuertradingsymbol', 'foreignField': 'ticker','as': 'string'}`
3. Stage 3: `$unwind` the 'string' from above
4. Stage 4: then match the dates within the same document
   `{'$expr': {'$eq': [ '$pdOfRpt', '$string.Date_unmodified']}}`
5. Stage 5: `$unwind`
6. Stage 6: select few fields that I need for analysis with `$project`
7. Stage 7: save results with `$out`

In all above steps - everything is fast as expected for these two collections except for Stage 7. However, I wanted to save this result as a separate collection. It has been running for over three hours and I have limited results for about 1million documents, but I do not see the result is saved in different collections. Interestingly enough when I run this query for `$limit` of 20000 documents, it gets saved in less than a minute. I do not understand why is it taking so long to save the result with about 1 million documents to be saved with `$out`. What am I missing here?

**Please note that I tried to use the visual query builder with compass and/or with terminal in my local.**

FULL PIPELINE:

```
`db.forms4InsTrader_final.aggregate([     {         '$match': {             'pdOfRpt': {                 '$gte': '2004-01-01',                  '$lte': '2020-12-31'             }         }     }, {         '$lookup': {             'from': 'TradeData',              'localField': 'issuertradingsymbol',              'foreignField': 'ticker',              'as': 'string'         }     }, {         '$unwind': {             'path': '$string',              'includeArrayIndex': 'Date_unmodified'         }     }, {         '$match': {             '$expr': {                 '$eq': [                     '$pdOfRpt', '$string.Date_unmodified'                 ]             }         }     }, {         '$project': {             'string.Adj Close': 1,              'string.Volume': 1,              'string.Close': 1,              'string.avg_Week_Vol': 1,              'string.db.forms4InsTrader_final.aggregate([     {         '$match': {             'pdOfRpt': {                 '$gte': '2004-01-01',                  '$lte': '2020-12-31'             }         }     }, {         '$lookup': {             'from': 'TradeData',              'localField': 'issuertradingsymbol',              'foreignField': 'ticker',              'as': 'string'         }     }, {         '$unwind': {             'path': '$string',              'includeArrayIndex': 'Date_unmodified'         }     }, {         '$match': {             '$expr': {                 '$eq': [                     '$pdOfRpt', '$string.Date_unmodified'                 ]             }         }     }, {         '$project': {             'string.Adj Close': 1,              'string.Volume': 1,              'string.Close': 1,              'string.avg_Week_Vol': 1,              'string.avg_Week_Adj_Close_Price': 1,              'string.Date_unmodified': 1,              'pdOfRpt': 1,              'issuercik': 1,              'issuertradingsymbol': 1,              'reportingownerid_rptownercik': 1,              'reportingowneraddress_rptownerzipcode': 1,              'reportingownerrelationship_isdirector': 1,              'reportingownerrelationship_isofficer': 1,              'reportingownerrelationship_istenpercentowner': 1,              'reportingownerrelationship_isother': 1,              'nonderivativetransaction_securitytitle_value': 1,              'nonderivativetransaction_transactionamounts_transactionshares_value': 1,              'nonderivativetransaction_transactionamounts_transactionpricepershare_value': 1,              'nonderivativetransaction_transactionamounts_transactionacquireddisposedcode_value': 1,              'nonderivativetransaction_posttransactionamounts_sharesownedfollowingtransaction_value': 1,              'derivativetransaction_securitytitle_value': 1,              'derivativetransaction_transactionamounts_transactionshares_value': 1,              'derivativetransaction_transactionamounts_transactionpricepershare_value': 1,              'derivativetransaction_transactionamounts_transactionacquireddisposedcode_value': 1,              'derivativetransaction_ownershipnature_directorindirectownership_value': 1,              'derivativetransaction_underlyingsecurity_underlyingsecuritytitle_value': 1,              'derivativetransaction_underlyingsecurity_underlyingsecurityshares_value': 1,              'derivativetransaction_posttransactionamounts_sharesownedfollowingtransaction_value': 1         }     }, {         '$limit': 1000000     }, {         '$out': 'TestAPril20'     } ])`
```

**Hacky way - so the compass generates temporary collection, you may export from it and reimport as a separate collection. VERY INEFFICIENT but hey it worked me doing manually until I find another solution**

Answer (score 2):

I vaguely remember this was the solution when it happened to me, let me know if **allowDiskUse** will solve your problem

from the mongodb documentation

> Pipeline stages have a limit of 100 megabytes of RAM. If a stage
> exceeds this limit, MongoDB will produce an error. To allow for the
> handling of large datasets, use the allowDiskUse option to enable
> aggregation pipeline stages to write data to temporary files.

it's a config flag, so this is a sample of how to use it

```
db.stocks.aggregate( [
      { $project : { cusip: 1, date: 1, price: 1, _id: 0 } },
      { $sort : { cusip : 1, date: 1 } }
   ],
   { allowDiskUse: true }
)
```

Comment: I do not think diskspace is issue here and obviously I tried it. I think its up something to do with config with output when the number of documents reaches certain threshold.